# rsync via multiple ssh connections with a key

Tags: ssh, rsync

I need to do a rsync from a target server with a server in the middle and I have the same public key on both the target and middle server.  I want to use that key so I don't have to do password authentication.

```
local --ssh--> middle --ssh--> target
```

Reading Method 1 of Using rsync through a firewall makes it seems like this is doable but I have been able to figure out the ssh part of the syntax of the command yet.

When I try

```
ssh -i $KEY -A user@middle ssh user@target
```

I get

```
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Clearly the agent forwarding isn't happening as I was expecting it to.

Ideally I'd like to fit it all in one command without have to put anything in ~/.ssh/config files.  What are all of the steps to do an rsync in this situation?

Thanks,
Everett

Comment: I assume you're doing someting along the lines of rsync -av -e "ssh -A  user@middle ssh user@target" [rest of the rsync command] ? And that doesn't work?

Comment: Did you start ssh-agent and add your identity(s)?  The '-A' will only "carry" identities loaded into the agent.

Comment: Yep.  First "ssh-add $KEY" then "ssh-agent" finally "ssh -A user@middle ssh user@target" and I still get the Permission denied.

Comment: A big part of the problem is that my public key on target had a copy/paste error so I couldn't do passwordless authentication to target in the first place.  Now that it's fixed the accepted answer below worked for me.  Thanks to all for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The '-A' will only "carry" identities loaded into ssh-agent. ('-i' on the command won't be enough.)

How about this something like this;

```
ssh-agent sh -c "ssh-add test_ident; rsync -avr --rsh='ssh -TA hostA ssh -TA ' foo/ hostB:/var/tmp/foo/"
```

Comment: This works for me.  For anyone following along substitute $KEY for test_ident, user@middle for hostA and target for hostB

Answer (score 1):

Personally I do this in two hops with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -fN root@middle.foo -L2211:target.foo:22
rsync "-e ssh -p 2211" /Users/me/dir1/ root@localhost:/backup/dir1/ -avz --progress --delete-after
rsync "-e ssh -p 2211" /Users/me/dir2/ root@localhost:/backup/dir2/ -avz --progress --delete-after
```

mod as required.

It seemed easier than playing with the rsync options and if your target and middle have your key you shouldn't be prompted.

Comment: Doing a "ssh -i $KEY -fN root@middle -L2211:target:22" works without prompting me for a password but when I try "rsync -e "ssh -p 2211" /dir/on/local/ root@localhost:/dir/on/target/ -avz --progress" I get asked for root@localhost's password.  What could I be missing?

Comment: See my last comment on the question.