# rsync from Drobo to Drobo

Tags: ssh, rsync, ssh-keygen, drobo

I'd like to run a backup rsync job from one Drobo to another. I've managed to get rsync and the ssh tools installed so that I can ssh from my desktop into backup@drobo1.local and then ssh into backup@drobo2.local from drobo1.local

What I need to setup is the backup user on Drobo2 which has a passwordless login from Drobo1.

How do I go about setting this up?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://serverfault.com/questions/172612/rsync-via-multiple-ssh-connections-with-a-key

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to [Setup public key authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260/how-do-i-setup-public-key-authentication) first.

You generate the key as the user which will initiate the backup on drobo1, and put it in the authorised_keys file (as a new single line in the file) for the backup user on drobo2.

Then you would have to setup the cronjob on drobo1 to do the rsync automated if needed.

Comment: This blog post looks like it's what you want to do exactly:  http://www.bryanrite.com/drobo-incremental-rsync-backups/