# rsync from remote ssh server with forwarded keys

Tags: ssh, rsync, ssh-agent

## Context

I am writing a synchronisation script to sync some web environments.

Ex: Update integration from production (mostly to fetch new database rows and uploaded files)

Some of my prerequisites are :

- Developers will use this script from the integration server
- DSA keys are needed to connect to production server
- Integration server can not store developer's private keys

## Question

I want developers to connect to the integration with `ssh -A` to allow the script to connect to the production server with their key:

```
+-------------+    SSH     +-------------+   rsync   +-------------+
| Developer   | ---------> | Integration | --------> |  Production |
|  computer   |            |   Platform  | <-------- |   platform  |
+-------------+            +-------------+           +-------------+
(priv DSA key)              (pub DSA key)             (pub DSA key)
```

It works just fine for `ssh` or `scp`, but I can't get rsync to use forwarded keys to connect to the production server.

I saw [similar questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/172612/rsync-via-multiple-ssh-connections-with-a-key) but where rsync is run from the user's computer and therefore the ssh key file may be pointed by `-i` option.

My concern is not passphrase related either since this script will be run by real users (not cron)

I tried to specify the remote shell to rsync like this :

`rsync -e "ssh -A" user@production`

But with no luck.

Comment: Have you tried using `rsync -e "ssh -i /path/to/key" .....`?

Comment: keys are not stored on the server rsync is run from.I updated my question with a schema to hopefully make that more clear.

Comment: I've just successfully done rsync-with-forwarded-agent, so I think there must be something more to the issue. What does the sshd log on the production server say about the connection attempts?

Comment: Can you copy/paste the rsync call ? Is it suppose to work without any specific options ? sshd does not log anything on prod server (which I'm not root on).

Answer (score 2):

Ok my problem was that I am "SSHing" on non standard port and I was trying to tell rsync via `--port=` option.

I used `rsync -e "ssh -p 1337" user@host:somepath/ .` instead and it works just fine out of the box.